# Kubernetes ingress rules for external service

Tags: kubernetes, external, nginx-ingress

This question is similar to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57764237/kubernetes-ingress-to-external-service) but this is more around the path in the rule that can be configured.

The ingress should be able to handle both the internal services and an external service. The Url for the external service should be something like http://host_name:80/es. When the user hits this url, this should be redirected to the external service.

The service definition and the ingress rule are configured as below but it leads to 404.
Where am i going wrong?

**Ingress rules**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: external-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: “nginx”
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ingress.class: “nginx”
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: “false”
spec:
  rules:
  - host:
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: external-ip
          servicePort: 80
        path: /es
```

**Service and End Point definitions**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: external-ip
spec:
  ports:
  - name: app
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: external-ip
subsets:
- addresses:
  - ip: <ip to external service>
  ports:
  - name: app
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
```

It works when i try with the URL http://host_name:80 and the following ingress rule. Please note the difference in the path in the ingress rule.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: external-service
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: “nginx”
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ingress.class: “nginx”
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: “false”
    spec:
      rules:
      - host:
        http:
          paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: external-ip
              servicePort: 80
            path: /
```

Comment: Please try without `kubernetes.io/ingress.class` annotation? And let me know if it solves it

Comment: @HelloWorld It does not work

Comment: What nginx and k8s version are you using (as in my k8s it seems to be working)? Also please explain how you deployed your nginx because I'd like to try to replicate it.

Comment: k8s is 1.14 and nginx-ingress-controller is 0.22.0

Comment: Does the external service you mentioned has `/es` path?

Comment: No. Thats the problem. I want the path for ingress but without the path for external service.

Comment: Use [rewrite-target](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/) as specified in nginx docs.

Comment: Tried rewrite-target as well but it does not help. I think rewrite-target is like URL rewriting for the browser and it may not rewrite the URL for the external service.

Answer (score 2):

There is a service that can echo my request back to me: https://postman-echo.com/, it will come useful later.
Here is its ip and it will simulate your external service:

```
$ dig postman-echo.com +short
107.23.20.188
```

It works as following:

```
$ curl 107.23.20.188/get | jq
{
  "args": {},
  "headers": {
    "x-forwarded-proto": "http",
    "x-forwarded-port": "80",
    "host": "107.23.20.188",
    "x-amzn-trace-id": "Root=1-5ebced9c-941e363cc28bf3529b8e7246",
    "user-agent": "curl/7.52.1",
    "accept": "*/*"
  },
  "url": "http://107.23.20.188/get"
}
```

So as you can see it sends me a json with all headers that I sent to it and most importantly - url with path it receives.

Here is the ingress yaml I used:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: external-service
  annotations:
    #kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - host:
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: external-ip
          servicePort: 80
        path: /es/(.*)
```

Service and Endpoint definition stays the same as yours with exception for endpoint IP. Here I used 107.23.20.188 (the postman-echo IP).

Now lets try to send some requests through nginx but first lets check whats ingress ip:

```
$ kubectl get ingress
NAME               HOSTS   ADDRESS         PORTS   AGE
external-service   *       192.168.39.96   80      20h
```

The ip is `192.168.39.96` and its private IP because I am running it on minikube but it should not matter.

```
$ curl -s 192.168.39.96/es/get
{
  "args": {},
  "headers": {
    "x-forwarded-proto": "http",
    "x-forwarded-port": "80",
    "host": "192.168.39.96",
    "x-amzn-trace-id": "Root=1-5ebcf259-6331e8c709656623f1a94ed4",
    "x-request-id": "d1545d1e8764da3cf57abb143faac4fb",
    "x-forwarded-host": "192.168.39.96",
    "x-original-uri": "/es/get",
    "x-scheme": "http",
    "user-agent": "curl/7.52.1",
    "accept": "*/*"
  },
  "url": "http://192.168.39.96/get"
}
```

so as you see I am sending request for path `/es/get` and echo server is receiving `/get`.

---

One thing I have noticed while writing this answer is that (maybe its just copy-paste error but) your quotes in annotations `”` are different than `"` and this may be causing that nginx is not processing annotations as it should. Im my case for some reason when I was copy-pasting your yaml it it was working but so it did without your annotations so that may be the reason I haven't noticed it earlier.