# OpenShift Ingress external service

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-ingress

tell me how to map an external resource as a service in openshift for use in ingress?
OKD 3.11.

I am creating a service type ExternalName

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: "sso"
  namespace: "test"
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: sso.test.org
```

Then I create a ingress

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example
  namespace: test
spec:
  rules:
    - host: app.test.org
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: ui
              servicePort: 8080
          - path: /auth
            backend:
              serviceName: sso
              servicePort: 443
          - path: /api
            backend:
              serviceName: api
              servicePort: 8080
```

But I get the error "Application is not available" for /auth.

/api and / works fine.

What could be the mistake?
I have a problem when accessing external ports with ssl. When accessing ports without ssl, no problems. It seems that haroute does not add https at the beginning of the address, and the request goes through http:// sso:443

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubernetes ingress rules for external service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61750709/kubernetes-ingress-rules-for-external-service)

Comment: @MariuszK. No, I have a problem when accessing external ports with ssl. When accessing ports without ssl, no problems. It seems that haroute does not add https at the beginning of the address, and the request goes through http:// sso:443

Comment: Does it work when you create separate ingress and add [backend protocol annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#backend-protocol)?

Comment: @MariuszK.In the current version of the OKD, haproxy is used as a router, and, unfortunately, there are no such annotations