# How to use Kubernetes as a proxy to make http://ip:port accessible via https://domain/suffix?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I want to make an endpoint running at `http://12.34.56.78:1234` accessible via `https://www.example.com/suffix`, whereas the latter endpoint is configured and exposed via Kubernetes and the former endpoint is standalone.

It is not possible to make changes to `http://12.34.56.78:1234` or `https://www.example.com/suffix`, the former is directly accessible over the internet and the latter must be exposed via Kubernetes. The only thing which may be changed is the Kubernetes configuration.

Therefore, I created the following ingress:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: ingress-controller
  namespace: ns
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - www.example.com
      secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
    - host: www.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /suffix
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              serviceName: proxy
              servicePort: 1234
```

and the following service:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: proxy
  namespace: ns
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 1234
      targetPort: 1234
  type: ExternalName
  sessionAffinity: None
  externalName: 12.34.56.78
```

According to https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/service-externalname-ip/494, using `Service` with `type: ExternalName` and an IP as externalName seems to work fine in general.

I also experimented with Endpoint but couldn't get it work either:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: proxy
  namespace: ns
subsets:
- addresses:
  - ip: 12.34.56.78
  ports:
  - name: proxy
    port: 1234
```

When calling `https://www.example.com/suffix`, I am getting `403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://www.example.com/suffix`

Any ideas how to get it to work?

Comment: Externalname does not accept(offically) IPv4 addresses. You need to enter canonical DNS here.

where is the server/pod that have this ip 12.34.56.78 ? In your cluster  or outside or the cluster ?

Comment: also you don't create endpoints yourself. endpoints are created when your service has pods that match its label selector (which are currently missing on your service)

Comment: @m303945 12.34.56.78 is outside the cluster. no dns name available. must work with ip.

Comment: @meaningqo according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57764237/kubernetes-ingress-to-external-service, creating an endpoint manually seems to be an option

Comment: Make your service headless service without selector.




Also what is your pod and node IP range. Maybe they are conflicting with your external IP.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubernetes Ingress to External Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57764237/kubernetes-ingress-to-external-service)

Comment: @m303945 no selector used in the reference service config shown above. IP conflicts can be ruled out.

Comment: @SYN thanks for the reference. but thats the same so answer i referenced above. i took the endpoint example from there. I guess the reason it doesn't work in my case is the external ip is only accessible via http whereas the ingress ip only via https.

Comment: I don't see any issues with ingress relaying your https connection to an http backend. Answering to the question in your title: link above is all you need. Now, if your Ingress returns with a 403: depending on your IG controller, could be that you're not querying the right FQDN, or more likely the backend is genuinely returning you with its own 403. Test the service: have you tested that you can query that Service from a node in your cluster? Test your IG configuration: are you sure those prefix/rewrite work?