# Ingress redirect to a localhost tcp service

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have a local website.
The website was created by a docker-compose and it is listening on a localhost port 3000.

When I try:

```
curl 127.0.0.1:3000
```

I can see the response.

What I did:

From my domain provider I edited the DNS to point to my server, then I changed nginx-ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: virtual-host-ingress
  namespace: ingress-basic
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-pp"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - nextformulainvesting.com
    secretName: ***
  rules:
  - host: "nextformulainvesting.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: e-frontend-saleor
            port:
              number: 80
```

and I created the service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: e-frontend-saleor
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
```

But with the service or without the service I receive the error `503 Service Temporarily Unavailable`.

How can I use nginx-ingress to point to my local TCP service?

Comment: Your website is listening on localhost:3000 and then you point dns to your server (I assume the externally accessible ip address of the server). I see a bit of a disconnect here. Is this website exposed or it only listens only on localhost (aka 127.0.0.1)?

Comment: I assume it is exposed, because otherwise you wouldn't be getting 503s, which is a valid response from a web server. Do you see anything in the logs of your web server?

Comment: So the issue is that the service is not pointing at anything at the moment, right? Since the Service is not selecting anything, you would need to create an Endpoint manually.

Comment: The server expose other services and websites inside the kubernetes cluster to the internet so it's configured well.
Now i have a service outside of the cluster because i don't have a kubernetes deployment:
i used docker-compose, ancthe website is listening on localhost:3000

Comment: an endpoint can't be loopback

Comment: i found the answer here, i think this is a dulicated post
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57764237/kubernetes-ingress-to-external-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57764237/kubernetes-ingress-to-external-service)

Comment: So, I assume, you resolved the problem, is that right?

Comment: yes i do , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify the issue I am posting a community wiki answer.

The answer that helped to resolve this issue is available at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57764237/kubernetes-ingress-to-external-service).  Based on that - the clue of the case is to create manually a Service and an Endpoint objects for external server.

After that one can create an Ingress object that will point to Service  `external-ip`  with adequate port .

Here are the examples of objects provided in [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57764237/kubernetes-ingress-to-external-service).

- Service and an Endpoint objects:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: external-ip
spec:
  ports:
  - name: app
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5678
  clusterIP: None
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: external-ip
subsets:
- addresses:
  - ip: 10.0.40.1
  ports:
  - name: app
    port: 5678
    protocol: TCP
```

- Ingress object:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: external-service
spec:
  rules:
  - host: service.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: external-ip
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```

See also [this reference](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/8631#issuecomment-104404768).

Answer (score 0):

Your **service** that you have created is for forwarding the traffic to **deployments**

As your service is running out side of Kubernetes cluster you should be using the **Endpoint** in this case

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: my-service
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - IP: <External IP>
    ports:
      - port: 3000
```

and you can use this **Endpoint** to ingress so that it will route the traffic.

**Ingress**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: virtual-host-ingress
  namespace: ingress-basic
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-pp"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - nextformulainvesting.com
    secretName: ***
  rules:
  - host: "nextformulainvesting.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-service
            port:
              number: 3000
```

Comment: The Endpoints  is invalid: subsets[0].addresses[0].ip: Invalid value: "127.0.0.1": may not be in the loopback range (127.0.0.0/8)

Comment: instead of 127.0.0.1 use the host machine IP. https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/8439#issuecomment-799801736

Comment: i have the ip and curl is OK.
so i changes ingress, but same 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable.
maybe because into the ingress it's defined SERVICE but i have an endpoint?

Comment: I created even the service, but same result.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: e-dashboard-saleor
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: e-dashboard-saleor
spec:
  selector:
    app: e-dashboard-saleor
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: app-dashboard-seleor
    port: 9000 # doesn't actually matter
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: e-dashboard-saleor
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 172.22.0.1
    ports:
      - port: 9000
        name: app-dashboard-seleor

9000 instead 3000 and the curl is ok